# bulk_create using ListCreateAPIView and ListSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

What is the difference between the above two methods?

I don't understand how they work, I did try googling, documentation, StackOverflow, medium articles but I don't understand the working.

Does ListCreateAPIView hit the create method as the length of the list? How to override that?
ListSerializer, I don't get this at all. So I gotta have a parent list serializer and child model serializer.

Where do I add the validations in each of these methods? And what if I want to override the fields or save extra information.

Basically, I am trying to create an API endpoint for bulk-creating users. That means apart from just the validations, I need to set the password for each user being created in the backend. How do I save it that way?

When I tried using the ListCreateAPIView, it kept throwing me the error ListSerializer is not iterable even after I set many = True.

Does ListCreateAPI works with just the model serializer or do I need to set the class to a ListSerializer class?

And, when I followed this medium article on bulk creating using ListSerializer, it kept telling me something like "JSON parse error - Expecting ',' delimiter: line 4 column 20 (char 72)"

I seriously don't get the working of both ListSerializer and ListCreateAPIView.

Any help would be highly appreciated. I am a newbie to this rest API thingy. Thanks.

My code is just basic

```
serializers.py

class BulkCreateUsersListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def create(self, validated_data):
        users = [UserModel(**item) for item in validated_data]
        return UserModel.objects.bulk_create(users)

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ...
        fields = ...
        list_serializer_class = BulkCreateUserListSerializers #commented when I tried using the ListCreateAPIView

views.py

class CreateBulkUsersAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = UserModel.objects.all()

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ if an array is passed, set serializer to many """
        if isinstance(kwargs.get('data', {}), list):
            kwargs['many'] = True
        return super(CreateBulkUsersAPIView, self).get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)
```

----Edit 1----
Traceback for "ListSerializer object is not iterable"

```
Template error:
In template C:\Users\Documents\Django Projects\startup\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\templates\rest_framework\horizontal\form.html, error at line 2
   'ListSerializer' object is not iterable
   1 : {% load rest_framework %}
   2 :  {% for field in form %} 
   3 :   {% if not field.read_only %}
   4 :     {% render_field field style=style %}
   5 :   {% endif %}
   6 : {% endfor %}
```

Comment: How exactly did you get `ListSerializer is not iterable even after I set many = True.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You had a lot of questions so I will choose one that will probably solve most of your problems:

[`ListCreateApiView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview) is for adding the functionality to `list` objects via `get` and `create` objects via `post` to your view.

The naming of `ListCreateApiView` doesn't mean that you can create objects using a list (although the confusion is understandable). You can still support that though, but you need to write your own `.create()` method in the view like so:

```
class CreateBulkUsersAPIView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = UserModel.objects.all()

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

The only difference with the default `create` is `get_serializer` needs to be called with `many=True` to support creating a list of objects.

Comment: Does this automatically hit the list_serializer_class' create method i have used on the UserSerializer? Or how?

Comment: According to the docs, it should: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-listserializer-behavior

Comment: It still says, "ListSerializer is not iterable" I have edited the traceback in the post...I'm guessing it has to with the drf templates